# Firestore cloud functions with version 9 modular

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to trigger cloud functions from firestore events (onWrite) but I don't find the correct way to implement it with the version 9 modular that I am using for this project. The whole documentation is with version 8 (named space).

Here is what I am trying to do (version 8) :

```js
export const documentWriteListener = functions.firestore
  .document('collection/{documentUid}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

    if (!change.before.exists) {
      // New document Created : add one to count
      db.doc(docRef).update({ numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(1) });
    } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
      // Updating existing document : Do nothing
    } else if (!change.after.exists) {
      // Deleting document : subtract one from count
      db.doc(docRef).update({ numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(-1) });
    }

    return;
  });
```

Here is my version 9 firebase initialization file :

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase/functions"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const functions = getFunctions(app);

export { db, auth, functions }
```

and here is what I've tried for the cloud function (that I put in an independent file actionsCount.js) :

```js
import { db, functions } from '../../firebase/initFirebase';
import { updateDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const documentWriteListeners = functions.firestore
  .document('actions/{documentUid}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

    const actionsCounter = doc(db, "actionsCount", "counter")
      
    if (!change.before.exists()) {
      // New document Created : add one to count
      await updateDoc(actionsCounter, { numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(1) });
    } else if (change.before.exists() && change.after.exists()) {
      // Updating existing document : Do nothing
    } else if (!change.after.exists()) {
      // Deleting document : subtract one from count
      await updateDoc(actionsCounter, { numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(-1) });
    }
    return;
})
```

When I deploy using `firebase deploy --only functions`, I get the error : **Cannot understand what targets to deploy/serve. No targets in firebase.json match '--only functions'**.

Should I put the function somewhere else ? Function is wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize Firebase Functions with the command `firebase init`. When you select `functions` and proceed with the setup, it'll create a new functions directory containing an `index.js/ts` file by default. That's where you add your Cloud Functions.

[image]

The `firebase-functions` SDK is not meant to be used on client side.

The directory structure would look like this:

[image]

`firebase deploy --only functions` will deploy the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this! Half a day haha
So I obviously ran the functions firebase init as suggested by Dharmaraj.
As per the modular (version 9), it looks like we can do it. So I basically tried to initialize the firebase sdk in the functions/index.js file with the version 8 (named-space) methods and it worked.
Here is the code :

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const fieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue; 

// Updating the Actions document count
exports.documentWriteListeners = functions.firestore.document('actions/{documentUid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
      
    if (!change.before.exists) {
        // New document Created : add one to count
        db.doc('actionsCount/counter').update({ numberOfDocs: fieldValue.increment(1) });
      } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
        // Updating existing document : Do nothing
      } else if (!change.after.exists) {
        // Deleting document : subtract one from count
        db.doc('actionsCount/counter').update({ numberOfDocs: fieldValue.increment(-1) });
      }

    return;
})
```

Comment: On a note, the Firebase Admin SDK that you use in Cloud Functions is not totally modular at the moment and hence you need to use the namespaced syntax.